# Why won't the specified image get deleted onclick when trying to iterate over a list of images?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm calling an API that contains images.  My goal's to delete any image I want onclick but it doesn't seem to be working.  In my `non-working` below, I get an error that says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefinedat HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (index.js:39)`

However, in my `working-code`, I can successfully delete the first image only onclick (obviously because of the `[0]`.

How would I be able to iterate through the list of images and onclick, delete the image?

Here's my `non-working` code:

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll(".the-img");

for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    img.style.display = "none";
    })
}
```

Here's my `working-code`:

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("the-img")[0];

img.addEventListener("click", function () {
    img.style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: `img.style`, `img` here is your array-like collection returned by `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your event handler, in the non-working code, you should use `this.style.display = "none"` so that `this` refers to the object clicked.

Doing otherwise, especially by indexing `img` array won't work.

Comment: you are welcome. Keep in mind the `this` keyword, in event handlers or loops as here, refers to the object firing the event (although old IE 8 in the case of inline event handlers sets `this` to window object).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.the-img').forEach(function(elem){
 elem.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  this.style.display = 'none';
 });
});
```

Comment: While this may be an answer to OP's problem, code-only answers are [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow. Please consider adding some explanation to the code provided as it will benefit both OP and future visitors.